# Storing Data in Session vs Sending Data into Database

Tags: php, database, mongodb, session

I am newbie in PHP and coding, I am developing a Webb App where I am collecting User Data, Form has 25-30 Different Field and data type, Can Anyone Tell me which would be more feasible for situation when we have large userbase.
1. Keeping all data in Session and then after final submission sending all fields data to Database
2. Sending each Field data one after another to database

Context is about making it feasible for resource usage in situation of large userbase. I am using mongodb.

Thanks for Your Answers.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I try to keep everything on the server’s load as much as possible, so clients have a lesser chance of catching an error. So your second option would be my choice, it’s more work, but I think it’s the safer choice.

*Ps: This is my opinion, but since I can’t comment on your question directly I had to write it in an answer.*